# generating a html email in php on submit

Tags: php, html

i am trying to figure out writing html in php file. it seems that php does not recognise all the html tag like font, img. it gave an error. I tried echo 'html stuff'; but it dont seem to work as well.

I have left out the other $var declaration in the code below. the script is working except when i tried to add font size or img tags.

```
  <?php
        header("Content-type: html");


        $message = "
        <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html>
         <head>
             <title>New Loan Enquiry</title>
        </head>
        <body>

        <h2><strong>Time of Enquiry: $today</strong></h2>

        Name: $name<br>
        Email: $email<br>
        Contact: $contact<br>
        Buy_Stage: $buystage<br>
        Property Type: $pty_type<br>
        Property Stage: $pty_stage<br>
        Purchase Price: $purchaseprice<br>
        Loan Amount: $loanamt<br>
        Rate Type: $rate_type<br>
        Comments: $comments<br><br>



        </body>
        </html>

        ";

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>
```

where did i go wrong? It recognize h2 but not h1 or h3.

do i have to do like

echo ' html';

for each html code line?

Comment: are you escaping your characters for the items you are adding?

Comment: You need to provide us with the code you want to work.

Comment: the mail() part is working properly, the value of those $strings are showing correctly on the email as well. My issue is the html formatting of the $message. for example i tried adding <font size="6"></font> to one of the lines Contact: $contact, but the email wont reflect the font size change. it could be due to the header issue which i did not put correctly as pointed out.

Comment: Please show me the code you are having a problem with, Like the image you are trying to add

Answer (score 1):

Please check [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) in documentation.

To send email with html content you need to do this way:

```
<?php

$to  = 'aidan@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'subject of email';

// message
$message = 'some html content...';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

and you don't need to use:

```
header("Content-type: html");
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";


$headers .= 'From: <from@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: cc@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

and remove

```
header("Content-type: html");
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it best to style `Html` email in `php` by using tables and inline styles like below. here is a link to reference. [Link](http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-send-nice-html-email-with-php_333.html), Sadly internal and external style sheets don't always work across different email clients.

```
    <?php
            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";




              $message = '<html>';
              $message .= '<head>';
              $message .= '<title>New Loan Enquiry</title>';
              $message .= '</head>';
              $message .= '<body>';

              $message .= '<h2><strong>Time of Enquiry: $today</strong></h2>';
              $message .= '<img src="http://YOUR_IMAGE_URL"/>;
              $message .= '<table width="auto" border="0" cellspacing="3px" cellpadding="0">';
              $message .= '<tr><td><strong>Name:</strong></td>';
              $message .= '<td style=" font-weight:300 color:#CC0000">\$name</td></tr>';
              $message .= '<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong></td>';
              $message .= '<td style=" font-weight:300 color:#CC0000">\$email</td></tr>';
              $message .= '<tr><td><strong>Contact:</strong></td>';
              $message .= '<td style=" font-weight:300 color:#CC0000">\$contact</td></tr>';
              $message .= '<tr><td><strong>Buy_Stage:</strong></td>';
              $message .= '<td style=" font-weight:300 color:#CC0000">\$buystage</td></tr>';
              $message .= '<tr><td><strong>Property Type:</strong></td>';
              $message .= '<td style=" font-weight:300 color:#CC0000">\$pty_type</td></tr>';
              $message .= '<tr><td><strong>Property Stage:</strong></td>';
              $message .= '<td style=" font-weight:300 color:#CC0000">\$pty_stage</td></tr>';
              $message .= '<tr><td><strong>Purchase Price:</strong></td>';
              $message .= '<td style=" font-weight:300 color:#CC0000">\$purchaseprice</td></tr>';
              $message .= '<tr><td><strong>Loan Amount:</strong></td>';
              $message .= '<td style=" font-weight:300 color:#CC0000">\$loanamt</td></tr>';
              $message .= '<tr><td><strong>Rate Type:</strong></td>';
              $message .= '<td>\$rate_type</td></tr>';
              $message .= '<tr><td><strong>Comments:</strong></td>';
              $message .= '<td style=" font-weight:300 color:#CC0000">\$comments</td></tr>';

            $message .= '</table>';

            $message .= '</body></html>';

            mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```